# Dynamic Where Condition Based on Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a parameter based on which I need to include or exclude one condition in a `where` clause. 
If the `CustomerType` parameter is blank, then I need to include a condition `CustomerType is null`, otherwise I need to exclude that `CustomerType is null` condition.

The SQL query is:

```
 IF(@CustomerType = Blank)
 BEGIN
    Select * From Customer
    Where
    (CustomerType IN(@Type) Or CustomerType is null)
 END
 Else
 Begin
    Select * From Customer
    Where
    CustomerType IN(@Type)
 End
```

Is there a better way to include or exclude this condition without using an `IF ELSE` condition like above?

Comment: `in(@type)` won't work as you are probably hoping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Select * From Customer
Where
(CustomerType is null AND @customertype ='')
OR 
CustomerType IN (@Type)
```

You need change your "IN" part , however.

Edit:

```
Select * From Customer
Where (@customertype ='') OR CustomerType IN (...)
```

To handle all those input in one stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FIND_CUSTOMER_BY_TYPE @TYPE VARCHAR(50) 
AS 
    BEGIN
    -- a lazy check on your parameters
    IF @TYPE LIKE '%[^0-9, ]%' BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid parameter',16,1);
        return;
    End;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500);

    SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS';
    IF @TYPE>''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE CUSTOMER_TYPE IN ('+@TYPE+')';
    EXEC(@SQL);
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

Your program can all this procedure with the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, when CustomerType Parameter is blank, I don't want to include "CustomerType is null" condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here Type is a drop-down parameter which contains different customer type codes 1,2,3 and -2. CustomerType parameter will be set to -2 if user selects all values in Type parameter to indicate that to include customer records without Type specified(Type is blank). When the user selects specific type(Type = 1), then it should return only customers of type 1. Hence the query should not include customers with null type. Can you kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: I think you need handle the data in your front-end program (or script) and generate different query statement for the database based on customer input. If you have to handle those different input, you need a stored procedure and generate the query dynamically. I'll post you a small sample but you need complete it by yourself.